# Retrieve nested parent child xml based on parent xml in sql xml

Tags: sql, xml, sqlxml

i have the following codes in [SQL XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML).  I need to insert a parent element into a parent element in SQL XML.

i have the following table.

```
Firstname   Lastname    class   mark
John        Lim          V      60
Wills       smith        V      80
Mark        Bay          V      75
Carl        mark         V      65
```

and this is my SQL XML statements

```
 Select 
  Firstname,
  Lastname,
  class,
  mark
  from Student for xml path('Students'), type
```

The result as below

```
<Students>
  <Firstname>John</Firstname>
  <Lastname>Lim</Lastname>
  <class>V</class>
  <mark>60</mark>
</Students>
<Students>
  <Firstname>Wills</Firstname>
  <Lastname>smith</Lastname>
  <class>V</class>
  <mark>80</mark>
</Students>
<Students>
  <Firstname>Mark</Firstname>
  <Lastname>Bay</Lastname>
  <class>V</class>
  <mark>75</mark>
</Students>
<Students>
  <Firstname>Carl</Firstname>
  <Lastname>mark</Lastname>
  <class>V</class>
  <mark>65</mark>
</Students>
```

I want the below result were class and mark tag are enclosed in another tag:

```
    <Students>
  <Firstname>John</Firstname>
  <Lastname>Lim</Lastname>
  <Details>
    <class>V</class>
    <mark>60</mark>
  </Details>  
</Students>
<Students>
  <Firstname>Wills</Firstname>
  <Lastname>smith</Lastname>
  <Details>
    <class>V</class>
    <mark>80</mark>
  </Details>
</Students>
<Students>
  <Firstname>Mark</Firstname>
  <Lastname>Bay</Lastname>
  <Details>
    <class>V</class>
    <mark>75</mark>
  </Details>
</Students>
<Students>
  <Firstname>Carl</Firstname>
  <Lastname>mark</Lastname>
  <Details>
    <class>V</class>
    <mark>65</mark>
  </Details>
</Students>
```

Any idea how to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a column alias.

```
select Firstname,
       Lastname,
       class as "Details/class",
       mark as "Details/mark"
from Student
for xml path('Students'), type
```